# Invalid Object name while inserting data into temporary table through JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to access one web application using URL(Web Browser). The web application uses JDBC calls to create and insert data into temporary table. Before table creation, I have put a statement to delete a temporary table to make sure that it is not present in database already.

Occasionally, I'm getting the below error in Tomcat logs.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid object name '#temp_table'
            at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:368)
            at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2820)
            at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2258)
            at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:632)
            at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.processResults(JtdsStatement.java:584)
            at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQL(JtdsStatement.java:546)
            at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeImpl(JtdsStatement.java:723)
            at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.execute(JtdsStatement.java:1160)
```

I have verified SQL Server Profiler Logs but not getting any clue. As per the stack trace, issue is coming while inserting the data. Please see the below code snippet:

```
                   ..
                   ..
stmt.executeUpdate(
    "IF object_id('tempdb..#temp_table') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp_table");
stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE #temp_table([context] [varchar](100) NULL)");
stmt.execute("INSERT INTO #temp_table(context) VALUES ('" + context + "')");
```

Can anyone please help to find the cause of this issue?

Comment: Are you sharing the same open connection across multiple sessions?

Comment: @AlexK. - Yes. There is a possibility of open connection across multiple sessions. Do I need to put my implementation in synchronized block?

Comment: Did you disable autocommit?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - what difference will it make if we disable autocommit? can you please elaborate?

Comment: @dev1991 I'm not sure if it makes a difference. Maybe I should have asked for a [mcve] instead. And could you please identify which line of code triggers the exception.